# I gets error after implementing useStack hook. error: (stack is undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array that its values convert to buttons. When clicked over each of the buttons, its value is written in the ul list. And when click over 'Pop', the last value is remove.

**expected output:**

[image]

I use from ***useStack*** hook to implement it. But after running, the output is a blank page and I receive this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: stack is undefined
```

**components.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {useStack} from './hooks'

export function Demo() {
    return (
        <div className="demo">
        <StackDemo/>
        </div>
    );
}

const words = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry', 'Grape'];
function StackDemo() {
    const {stack, push, pop} = useStack();
    return (<div>
        {words.map((word, index) => <button key={index} onClick={() => push(word)}>{word}</button>)}
        <button onClick={pop}>» Pop</button>
        <ul>
            {stack.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>)}
        </ul>
    </div>);
}
```

**hooks.js:**

```
import {useState} from 'react';

export function useStack() {
    const [array,setArray] = useState([]);

    const add = (value) => {
        return setArray(array.push(value));
    }
    const del = () => {
        return setArray(array.pop());
    }

    return {array, add, del};
}
```

Of course, if I edit components.js:

// const **{stack, push, pop}** = useStack(); **to** // const **[stack, push, pop]** = useStack();

And edit hooks.js:

// return **{array, add, del}** to // return **[array, add, del]**

Then output displayed:
[image]

But when I click on one of them, output will become blank page, and I receive this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: stack.map is not a function
```

What is the problem? How should I assign **useStack output** to **const {stack, push, pop}** ??

Thanks for any help.

Comment: your `useStack` returns an object with keys `array`, `add` and `del`. You'll have to rename those, as well as the functions (assuming you continue to use the object shorthand) to `stack`, `push` and `pop` in order to use it the way you are.

Comment: PS your `add` and `del` (or `push` and `pop` if you rename them to that) won't work as I think you want them to. But that's a different question.

Comment: @RobinZigmond why the names should be the same? I did it, now the page become blank and gives me: (stack.map is not a function)

Comment: ah, that new error will be because of the problems I mentioned in my second comment

Comment: as for why the names should be the same, I don't understand the question. If `useStack` returns an object whose only keys are `array`, `add` and `del`, why do you expect it to have a `stack` property that is anything other than `undefined`?

Comment: @RobinZigmond I wanted stack & push & pop replaced with array & add & del. But according to Catalyst's answer,  I should do it by array formating.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes. You right. I now understand that what you mean. I commented under Catalyst's post. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with the `useStack` hook:

- Your `add` function:

```js
const add = (value) => {
    return setArray(array.push(value));
}
```

[`array.push` returns a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#return_value) (the new array's length), *not* the array after the addition of the new element. This causes the white page (caused by a JavaScript `TypeError`, because now `stack` is not an array anymore).

To fix this, I'd suggest:

```js
const add = (value) => {
    return setArray(array.concat(value));
}
```

- Your `del` function:

```js
const del = () => {
    return setArray(array.pop());
}
```

In this case, [`array.pop` returns the value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop#return_value) that was just popped, so now stack is a string instead of an array.

To fix this, I'd suggest:

```js
const del = () => {
    return setArray(array.slice(1));
}
```

Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-neumann-41ltx?file=/src/App.js.

Comment: Thanks very much. That was a very good point about push & pop. Of course 'slice(1)' should be changed to 'slice(0, array.length-1)', since I want be delete the last value. Also, is this maybe the stack & push & pop be inside {} instead []? (and as a result, array & add & del be inside {}). because in the project, they want me that change the hooks.js.

Comment: I found my answer: I changed the names of 'array' & 'add' & 'del' to 'stack' & 'push' & 'pop'. And  in the components.js: "const {stack, push, pop} = useStack();" And in the hooks.js: "return {stack, push, pop};".